# How do you serialize types in an inheritance chain with protobuf-net surrogates?

Tags: c#, inheritance, protobuf-net

If you have two (or more) classes in an ineritance chain (GeoCoordinate inherits from PointF2D in this case) how do you use surrogates correctly to allow serialization of either type?

As an example, I have these two surrogate classes

```
    public class SerializablePointF2D
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public double[] Values { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator SerializablePointF2D(PointF2D value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new SerializablePointF2D {Values = value.ToArrayCopy()} ;
        }`enter code here`
        public static implicit operator PointF2D(SerializablePointF2D value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new PointF2D(value.Values);
        }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SerializableGeoCoordinate        {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public double[] Values { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator SerializableGeoCoordinate(GeoCoordinate value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new SerializableGeoCoordinate { Values = value.ToArrayCopy() };
        }
        public static implicit operator GeoCoordinate(SerializableGeoCoordinate value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new GeoCoordinate(value.Values);
        }
    }
```

And this code setting up the model

```
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        //GeoCoordinate
        model.Add(typeof(PrimitiveSimpleF2D), false).AddSubType(1, typeof(PointF2D));
        model.Add(typeof(PointF2D), false).AddSubType(4, typeof(GeoCoordinate)).SetSurrogate(typeof(SerializablePointF2D));            
        model.Add(typeof(GeoCoordinate), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(SerializableGeoCoordinate));
```

When I attempt to serialize this it gets serialized as a PointF2D rather than a GeoCoordinate. I've tried every combination of ordering I can think of
EDIT:
Based on Marc's code below I tried

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SerializablePointF2D
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public double[] Values { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator SerializablePointF2D(PointF2D value)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;
            var geoCoordinate = value as GeoCoordinate;
            if (geoCoordinate != null) return new SerializableGeoCoordinate
            {
                Values = geoCoordinate.ToArrayCopy(),
            };
            return new SerializablePointF2D {Values = value.ToArrayCopy()};
        }
        public static implicit operator PointF2D(SerializablePointF2D value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new PointF2D(value.Values);
        }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SerializableGeoCoordinate:SerializablePointF2D
    {

    }
```

Which I thought looked right. It failed with

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Unexpected sub-type: OsmSharp.Serialization.OsmSharpSerializer+SerializableGeoCoordinate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it based on both the answers (Thanks!!!)

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(2, typeof(SerializableGeoCoordinate))]
    public class SerializablePointF2D
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public double[] Values { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator SerializablePointF2D(PointF2D value)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;
            var geoCoordinate = value as GeoCoordinate;
            if (geoCoordinate != null) return new SerializableGeoCoordinate
            {
                Values = geoCoordinate.ToArrayCopy(),
            };
            return new SerializablePointF2D {Values = value.ToArrayCopy()};
        }
        public static implicit operator PointF2D(SerializablePointF2D value)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;
            var geoCoordinate = value as SerializableGeoCoordinate;
            if (geoCoordinate != null)
            {
                return new GeoCoordinate(geoCoordinate.Values);
            }
            return new PointF2D (value.Values );
        }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class SerializableGeoCoordinate:SerializablePointF2D
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So: you have 3 non-serializable types, and you want to add surrogates for them? Perhaps the trick here is to realise that protobuf-net always goes to the root of any inheritance model - so if a surrogate is declared there: ***it wins***; surrogates take over the serialization/deserialization process completely. The following works by making the *surrogates* mimic the inheritance of the originals - any use?

```
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using System;
public class A
{
    // we'll use this to detect how it was constructed
    public bool ViaOperator { get; set; }

    public int X { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
public class C : B
{
    public int Z { get; set; }
}


[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(1, typeof(BSer))]
public class ASer
{
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int X { get; set; }

    protected virtual A ToA()
    {
        return new A { X = X };
    }

    public static implicit operator A(ASer value)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        var a = value.ToA();
        a.ViaOperator = true;
        return a;
    }
    public static implicit operator ASer(A value)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        var c = value as C;
        if(c != null) return new CSer {
            X = c.X, Y = c.Y, Z = c.Z};
        var b = value as B;
        if(b != null) return new BSer {
            X = b.X, Y = b.Y };
        return new ASer { X = value.X };
    }
}
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(1, typeof(CSer))]
public class BSer : ASer
{
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int Y { get; set; }

    protected override A ToA()
    {
        return new B { X = X, Y = Y };
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class CSer : BSer
{
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int Z { get; set; }

    protected override A ToA()
    {
        return new C { X = X, Y = Y, Z = Z };
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        model.Add(typeof(A), false).AddSubType(2, typeof(B)).SetSurrogate(typeof(ASer));
        model[typeof(B)].AddSubType(2, typeof(C));

        A obj = new B { X = 1, Y = 2 };

        var clone = (B)model.DeepClone(obj);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", clone.X, clone.Y, clone.ViaOperator);

    }
}
```

Comment: My two classes are data identical, how would I change your code to work for these classes (my attempt failed). Should return new A { X = value.X }; be return new ASer { X = value.X };??

Comment: @DavidHayes OOPS! yes, my mistake. Also: what is the reason you want to use surrogates if they are data-identical? Did you know protobuf-net can serialize private fields and side-step constructors, if needed? You *could* just configure the original types to serialize directly, even if they don't expose friendly-looking APIs,

Comment: I'll be running it on WP7/8 so IIRC the private field stuff didn't work on the less full featured frameworks

Comment: @David fair enough - that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ProtoInclude` in `PointF2D` to include `GeoCoordinate`? Like this:

```
[Serializable,
ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields, ImplicitFirstTag = 1), 
ProtoInclude(20, "GeoCoordinate")]
public class PointF2D
{
...etc...
}
```

That should force it to use the surrogate `SerializableGeoCoordinate`.

Comment: I suspect the entire point of the surrogate is that the `PointF2D` can't be directly manipulated. Of course, everything can be configured via the type-model instead of attributes, but sometimes it is desirable to reshape the data for serialization.